# mvn:install to place my jar in nexus remote repository

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I am using maven in eclipse  (m2 eclipse)

When i execute mvn:install i want my jar(artifact) to be installed in the nexus repository which is located on the server(right now the installed jar is placed in the local system repository).. how can i do that ?

[image]

I even changed this to my local repository address

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Typically, you'd use `mvn deploy` to deploy to a non-local repository.

You will, of course, need to have the repo configured, either in your maven settings.xml or in the project POM.

As we always use the same internal repo, I've done this in the Maven settings.xml, more precisely, the "profiles" section.

Here is my config for reference:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>artifactory</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-releases</name>
          <url>http://repo.example.com/libs-releases</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshots</name>
          <url>http://repo.example.com/libs-snapshots</url>
          <snapshots />
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-releases</name>
          <url>http://repo.example.com/plugins-releases</url>
          <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```